# How to get the values for every group of the top 3 types

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group

I've got this table `ratings`:

| id | user_id | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Rest | 4 |
| 1 | 0 | Bar | 3 |
| 2 | 0 | Cine | 2 |
| 3 | 0 | Cafe | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | Rest | 4 |
| 5 | 1 | Bar | 3 |
| 6 | 1 | Cine | 2 |
| 7 | 1 | Cafe | 5 |
| 8 | 2 | Rest | 4 |
| 9 | 2 | Bar | 3 |
| 10 | 3 | Cine | 2 |
| 11 | 3 | Cafe | 5 |

I want to have a table with a row for every pair `(user_id, type)` for the top 3 rated types through all users (ranked by `sum(value)` across the whole table).

Desired result:

| user_id | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Rest | 4 |
| 0 | Cafe | 1 |
| 0 | Bar | 3 |
| 1 | Rest | 4 |
| 1 | Cafe | 5 |
| 1 | Bar | 3 |
| 2 | Rest | 4 |
| 3 | Cafe | 5 |
| 2 | Bar | 3 |

I was able to do this with two queries, one to get the top 3 and then another to get the rows where the type matches the top 3 types.

Does someone know how to fit this into a single query?

Comment: I don't quite understand the output.  Why does user 3 only have one row and why does user 0 have Cafe instead of Cine?

Comment: because the top 3 I want is not within the group, but within all ratings.
The top 3 types are:
Rest -> 12
Cafe -> 11
Bar   -> 9
Therefore the rows are filtered to only show the rows that rate the top 3 types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Get rows per user for the 3 highest ranking types, where types are ranked by the total sum of their value across the whole table.*

So it's not exactly about *the top 3 types per user*, but about the *top 3 types overall*. Not all users will have rows for the top 3 types, even if there would be 3 or more types for the user.

Strategy:
Aggregate to get summed values per type (`type_rnk`).
Take only the top 3. (Break ties ...)
Join back to main table, eliminating any other types.
Order result by `user_id, type_rnk DESC`

```sql
SELECT r.user_id, r.type, r.value
FROM   ratings r
JOIN  (
   SELECT type, sum(value) AS type_rnk
   FROM   ratings
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY type_rnk DESC, type  -- tiebreaker
   LIMIT  3   -- strictly the top 3
   ) v USING (type)
ORDER  BY user_id, type_rnk DESC;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=639e344522293dee5d476ccf53699cba)*

Since multiple types can have the same ranking, I added `type` to the sort order to break ties alphabetically by their name (as you did not specify otherwise).

Turns out, we don't need  [**window functions**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) - the ones with `OVER` and, optionally, `PARTITION` for this. (Since you asked in a comment).

Answer (score -1):

I think you just want `row_number()`.  Based on your results, you seem to want three rows per type, with the highest value:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by value desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

Your description suggests that you might just want this per user, which is a slight tweak:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user order by value desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

Comment: That looks really nice, would you mind explaining the over / partition bit to clarify the answer?

Comment: @BrunoLoops . . . https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html.

Comment: @BrunoLoops: Why did you accept this answer? It clearly doesn't do what you asked for.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks for noticing, I had solved it in another way thanks to this answer. However I wasn't able to confirm that the solution suggested by Gordon wasn't right that's why I accepted it.
Now your answer looks way better, I'll accept that instead, thank you